# Encrypt TMX tilemaps?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, tmx

I am using TMX tilemaps (Tiled) in an app I am creating.

I was curious if anyone else has encrypted or changed their tilemaps in a way that a 'malicious' user wouldn't know that the file is a TMX map.

I basically want my TMX to be hidden in a way that anyone opening up the application and inspecting its contents, couldn't open the TMX and change the map in a way that they know were secret items are or change it so that enemies aren't as strong etc... etc.. I gotta keep some secrets in my game :-)

Comment: zip it and change the file extension, this will be enough to defend against 99% of the curious

Comment: I agree, that would defend against the curious. I would love to see someone's implementation of this procedure. Do you know of a write up or tutorial anywhere? @LearnCocos2D